# CSS buttons doesnt render properly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, render

I cannot get the comment buttons to render properly in IE7 and IE8. This is the URL: http://bit.ly/dJkZuI

It works fine in all other browsers. I have been banging my head the past days trying to solve it with no success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with the fact that you have two anchor tags inside that div, not just one. If you hover over each of those images, you will see that they both go to a different URL.

Your CSS is set up to have the anchors in that div take up space, so even though the anchor has no content inside it, it is still taking up the same amount of space. Remove the anchor that doesn't have any text and the problem should go away.

You also have javascript errors that you should probably clean up, but that shouldn't be related to this specific issue.

Comment: Agreed. The two `a` tags is the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my question! Regarding the javascript errors, there are only warnings that I can see? Not actual errors?

Comment: IE says this: 
Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Comment: Its because it is customized to be resized within the Facebook canvas application.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in IE7.  Perhaps you made changes and your browser was still using a cached version of the stylesheet?

Comment: No I didnt. I tried it once in IE7, and tried it on three different systems on IE8. All with the same result. And if you dont mind, could you please up vote this question? Your answer does obviously not solve my issue.

Comment: It may not "solve your issue", but I am telling you that it works fine for me in IE7.  Both the default and hover states seem to be working as intended.

Comment: @Ottas welcome to SO. It is no "styled" to ask for an upvote, this come with quality questions (not saying this is not one), remember to treat people who are trying to help YOU with respect,"Your answer does obviously not solve my issue" may not be the best way to go :)

Comment: Trufa, firstly appreciate that I am new to this community and learning. Secondly, if that came across that not appreciative, then it is not my intention. To be honest, I think you might have read it differently. Note: "If you dont mind" stating that I am asking with respect. And giving the reason of the favour: "Your answer does obviously not solve my issue". I do not know of any other way to change that... maybe if I should have tried "The answer you gave was unfortunately only a statement and not a solution, and therefor did not resolve the issue for me."

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that IE is confused by the invalid HTML. `a` elements may not contain block elements such as `div`s.

There are several other errors in your HTML. You should correct them, too:

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.the-artifice.com%2ffilm%2f

Answer (score 0):

It's not just IE7 that is rendering it this way. IE8 does as well. The problem is that you have an `a` tag outside of the div, and then another inside. You can't do that.